# catalogue currency

Tags: magento2, catalog, currency

the default currency on magento2 appears to be the us dollar, i need to set the currency in the store to be SRD but setting the store's base currency to SRD doesn't seem to set my catalogue currency to be the same

update: appearently it does set the currency to SRD but it uses the wrong symbol creating a lot of confusion if the base currency is SRD but the display currency is USD[image]

the 71 in this screenshot is in USD but the 1000 is in SRD
it should say "SRD 1000" to prevent confusion